# retrieving environment variable in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5 Application. I created some custom classes and added them in the project using *classmap* in the *composer.json* and until here everything work perfectly, but now I need to access some environment variables (the ones saved in the `.env` file) I tried:

```
$variable= env('MyVariable','MydefaultValue');
```

But it's not working, also tried including `use App;`and then retrieving the variable like this:

```
$variable= App::environment('MyVariable', 'MydefaultValue');
```

But it's not working. So now I'm wondering if is it possible, or I am not retrieving the variable properly?

Comment: Try to use getenv() or $_ENV array. Bu firstly try to do `php artisan config:clear` than try `$variable= env('MyVariable','MydefaultValue');`

Answer (score 1):

you should do it in this way:

```
{{ env('MyVariable') }}
```

*MyVariable* is the name of the variable, in your .env file would look like this:

```
MyVariable=Something
```

Hope it help you out!

Best regards.